# Openlayers directive angularjs layer-clustering

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-openlayers

I used angular-openlayers-directive from this link: https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-openlayers-directive

I want to achieve this effect: http://tombatossals.github.io/angular-openlayers-directive/examples/059-layer-clustering.html

Unfortunately, only a map with no round points is displayed in my application. My code is the same as in the github example.

My code:

```
function createPointStyle(color, text) {
            var options = {
                image: new ol.style.Circle({
                    radius: 10,
                    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                        color: color,
                        opacity: 0.6
                    }),
                    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                        color: 'white',
                        opacity: 0.4
                    })
                })
            };
            if (text) {
                options.text = new ol.style.Text({
                    text: text,
                    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                        color: 'white'
                    })
                });
            }
            return new ol.style.Style(options);
        }
        function createIconStyle() {
            return new ol.style.Style({
                image: new ol.style.Icon({
                    anchor: [0.5, 1],
                    anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
                    anchorYUnits: 'fraction',
                    opacity: 0.90,
                    src: 'resource/img/mapin.png'
                })
            });
        }
        function getStyle(feature) {
            // Take car we use clustering, thus possibly have multiple features in one
            var features = feature.get('features');
            var style = null;
            // Icon base style ?
            if ($scope.icon) {
                style = createIconStyle();
            }
            // Circle + txt base style
            // Add number of clustered item in this case
            else if (features && features.length > 1) {
                style = createPointStyle('blue', features.length.toFixed());
            } else {
                style = createPointStyle('blue');
            }
            return [style];
        }
        angular.extend($scope, {
            center: {
                lat: 43.88,
                lon: 7.57,
                zoom: 2
            },
            clusters: {
                clustering: true,
                clusteringDistance: 40,
                source: {
                    type: 'KML',
                    projection: 'EPSG:3857',
                    url: 'resource/kml/earthquakes.kml'
                },
                style: getStyle
            },
            // Default to circles
            icon: false
        });
```

Someone knows why it does not work?

Comment: Have you added `ol-layer-properties="clusters"` attribute to element with `ol-layer` tag?

Comment: Yes, this is my HTML code : 
<openlayers ol-center="center" height="400px">
        <ol-layer ol-layer-properties="clusters"></ol-layer>
    </openlayers>